# How to send a POST request to my NodeJS server with an object using AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, postman

Everything works as intended using POSTMAN. but from my application, I don't get the same results, or no results to be precise.

Here is my React code:

```
const jsonObj = JSON.stringify({ email, subject, body })

const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON',                
    }
}

try {            
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000', jsonObj, config); 
                    
    console.log(response);
} catch (e) {            
    console.log(e);
}
```

And this is my NodeJS code:

```
import http from 'http';

function response(res, statusCode, contentType, message) {  
    res.writeHead(statusCode, { "Content-Type": contentType, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://<SERVER_NAME>:<PORT>" });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ message }));
}

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/' && req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            let body = '';

            req.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk.toString();

            });

            req.on('end', () => console.log(JSON.parse(body)));
            response(res, 201, 'application/json', 'Email was successfully sent...');
        } catch(e) {
            response(res, 500, 'application/json', e);
        }
    }
})

server.listen(<PORT>, () => console.log('Server listening...'));
```

I tried AXIOS post requests using `text/plain` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Both works as intended, but I need to post the data as JSON. When I remove the headers object from AXIOS, it works, but this is because the default header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So my question is: How do I post an object with AXIOS as JSON? because it is automatically serialized as JSON according to what I've read!

EDIT:

Apparently the problem is not exclusive to AXIOS, I tried the same thing with FETCH API and the problem persists, the code won't work if I set `Content-Type` to `application/json`

EDIT 2:

It works normally in cURL as well as POSTMAN. The problem is still with my application.

I tried fetching data from jsonplaceholder.typicode and it works. So maybe the problem is with NodeJS, but again it worked with everything except my client side code. Absolutely no idea what is going on.

EDIT 3:

It worked after converting my server file from raw NodeJS to express, and it worked. So maybe the problem is with parsing JSON data.

Comment: Start with not `JSON.stringify`ing it? :)

Comment: Tried it before stringifying it! Still no results...

Answer (score 0):

For axios we don't need to stringify the javascript object.

```
const jsonObj = { email, subject, body };

const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON',                
    }
}

try {            
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000', jsonObj, config); 
                    
    console.log(response);
} catch (e) {            
    console.log(e);
}
```

Try node js code some thing like this:

```
function getPostData(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let body = ''
            req.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk.toString()
            })
            req.on('end', () => {
                resolve(body)
            })

        } catch (error) {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
}
const body = await getPostData(req);
const { email, subject, body} = JSON.parse(body)
        const product = {
            email,
            subject,
            body
        }

        res.writeHead(201, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        return res.end(JSON.stringify(product))
```

Comment: I tried this solution before stringifying it out of desperation! not working unfortunately.

Comment: Try with traditional object creation: const jsonObj = { email:'example@example.com', subject:'sample', body: 'Sample body' };

Comment: I have edited answe for node js as well check that as well

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work either! still no response!